# How to get posted data from from to email in SocialEngine?

Tags: php, socialengine

I edited standard contact form in SocialEngine. Added new 4 fields to it - BirthDate, address, country & postal code field.

First question - how to properly set the default value of Country Select = "USA"?

Second question - how to get posted data from new form's fields (BirthDate, address, country & postal code) to user's email? How need to edit my controller?

My code:

```
class Pagecontact_Form_Contact extends Engine_Form
{
     private $page_id;

  public function __construct($page_id)
  {
    $this->page_id = $page_id;

    parent::__construct();
  }

    public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    $this
      ->setTitle('Send Message to Apply for Sponsorship')
      ->setAttrib('id', 'page_edit_form_contact')
      ->setAttrib('class', 'global_form');

        $topicsTbl = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('topics', 'pagecontact');
        $topics = $topicsTbl->getTopics($this->page_id);

        $viewer_id = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();

        $options[0] = '';
        foreach($topics as $topic)
        {
            $options[$topic['topic_id']] = $topic['topic_name'];
        }

    $this->addElement('Date', 'birthdate', array('label' => 'Birthdate:',
            'class' => 'date_class', 'name' => 'birthdate'));

    $this->addElement('Text', 'address', array('label' => 'Address:',
            'class' => 'address_class', 'name' => 'address'));

    $this->addElement('Select', 'country', array('label' => 'Country:',
            'class' => 'country_class', 'name' => 'country')); //->setValue("USA");

    $this->addElement('Text', 'postal', array('label' => 'Postal Code:',
            'class' => 'postal_class', 'name' => 'postal'));

    $this->addElement('Select', 'topic', array(
      'label' => 'PAGECONTACT_Topic',
            'class' => 'topic_class',
      'multiOptions' => $options,
    ));

    $this->getElement('topic')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('class','element_label_class topic_label_class');

      $this->addElement('Hidden', 'visitor', array(
                'value' => 0,
                'order' => 3,
        ));

      if ($viewer_id == 0)
      {
          $this->addElement('Text', 'sender_name', array(
                'label' => 'PAGECONTACT_Full name',
                'class' => 'subject_class',
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'size' => 37,
                'validators' => array(
                    array('NotEmpty', true),
                    array('StringLength', false, array(1, 64)),
                ),
                'filters' => array(
                    'StripTags',
                    new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
                    new Engine_Filter_EnableLinks(),
                ),
      ));

      $this->getElement('sender_name')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('class','element_label_class sender_name_label_class');

          $this->addElement('Text', 'sender_email', array(
                'label' => 'PAGECONTACT_Email',
                'class' => 'subject_class',
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'size' => 37,
                'validators' => array(
                    array('NotEmpty', true),
                    array('StringLength', false, array(1, 64)),
                ),
                'filters' => array(
                    'StripTags',
                    new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
                    new Engine_Filter_EnableLinks(),
                ),
      ));

      $this->getElement('sender_email')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('class','element_label_class sender_email_label_class');

            $this->addElement('Hidden', 'visitor', array(
                'value' => 1,
                'order' => 3,
            ));
      }

    $this->addElement('Text', 'subject', array(
      'label' => 'PAGECONTACT_Subject',
            'class' => 'subject_class',
      'allowEmpty' => false,
            'size' => 37,
      'validators' => array(
        array('NotEmpty', true),
        array('StringLength', false, array(1, 64)),
      ),
      'filters' => array(
        'StripTags',
        new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
        new Engine_Filter_EnableLinks(),
      ),
    ));

    $this->getElement('subject')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('class','element_label_class subject_label_class');

    $this->addElement('Textarea', 'message', array(
      'label' => 'PAGECONTACT_Message',
      'maxlength' => '512',
            'class' => 'message_class',
      'filters' => array(
        new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
        new Engine_Filter_Html(array('AllowedTags' => 'a'))
      ),
    ));

    $this->getElement('message')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('class','element_label_class message_label_class');

    $this->addElement('Hidden', 'page_id', array(
            'value' => $this->page_id,
            'order' => 7,
        ));


        $this->addElement('Button', 'send', array(
            'label' => 'Send',
            'type' => 'button',
            'class' => 'btn_send_class',
            'name' => 'submitted'
    ));

  }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function sendAction()
  {
    $page_id = $this->_getParam('page_id');
    $topic_id = $this->_getParam('topic_id');
    $subject = $this->_getParam('subject');
    $message = $this->_getParam('message');
    $senderName = $this->_getParam('sender_name');
    $senderEmail = $this->_getParam('sender_email');
    $birthDate = $this->getRequest()->getPost('birthdate'); // Empty set
    $address = $this->getRequest()->getPost('adress'); // Empty set
    $country = "USA"; // Works
    $postal = $this->getRequest()->getPost('postal'); // Empty set

    $pagesTbl = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('pages', 'page');
    $select = $pagesTbl->select()
        ->from(array($pagesTbl->info('name')), array('displayname'))
        ->where('page_id = ?', $page_id);
    $query = $select->query();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    $pageName = $result[0]['displayname'];

    $viewer = $this->_helper->api()->user()->getViewer();
    $user_id = $viewer->getIdentity();

    $topicsTbl = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('topics', 'pagecontact');
    $emails = $topicsTbl->getEmails($page_id, $topic_id);

    $i = 0;
    $emails = explode(',',$emails);

    foreach($emails as $email) {
      $emails[$i] = trim($email);
      $i++;
    }

    if ($user_id != 0) {
      $senderName = $viewer['displayname'];
      $senderEmail = $viewer['email'];
    }

    foreach($emails as $email) {
      // Make params
      $mail_settings = array(
        'date' => time(),
        'page_name' => $pageName,
        'sender_name' => $senderName,
        'sender_email' => $senderEmail,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'message' => $message." ".$birthDate." ".$address." ".$country." ".$postal,
      );

      // send email
      Engine_Api::_()->getApi('mail', 'core')->sendSystem(
        $email,
        'pagecontact_template',
        $mail_settings
      );
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: If someone know the answer, please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene,

There is not country field in the your form. But you can do in controller where you are calling the form function like.

```
    {
        $form->getElement('country')->setvalue('USA');
    }
```

Please feel free to ask your questions.